# "if you're dropping by again, do pop in"

Tags: meaning, idioms, phrasal-verbs

In the movie "Life of Brian" (1979), when the three wise men are leaving, Brian's mother tell them "Well, if you're dropping by again, do pop in." Does it means "the next time you want to come here, there is no need to prior notice" or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that if they come back to the town or area again, that they should stop by their place again.

For example, lets say you have a friend that lives in London, and you sometimes go to London for work. So it's just like your friend telling you to visit her the next time you're in London. So the ultimate reason why the person/people would be there is likely not to see that person/people, but if they are in the place for another reason, do pop in.

Comment: btw, it is done in an intentionally archaic form [early - mid 1900's] as much of Python's dialog is. Pretty sure no-one would use 'pop in' anymore.